# Can not save a list to a session/ViewBag variable

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC action where I get some data from the UI. Now, I want to assign those data to an object, and then save that object in a session list. But, with every request, the count of the session is 0.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(Purchase purchase)
{
    if(Session["AddedProduct"] == null)
    {
        List<AddedProductView> addedProducts = new List<AddedProductView>();
        AddedProductView addedProductView = new AddedProductView();
        addedProductView.ProductId = purchase.ProductId;

        addedProducts.Add(addedProductView);

        Session["AddedProduct"] = addedProducts;
    }
    else
    {
        List<AddedProductView> addedProducts = (List<AddedProductView>)Session["AddedProduct"];
        AddedProductView addedProductView = new AddedProductView();
        addedProductView.ProductId = purchase.ProductId;


        addedProducts.Add(addedProductView);

        Session["AddedProduct"] = addedProducts;                
    }   

    return View();
}
```

Here, with every request, I end up with a new list, which means every time executes the if condition. I have serialized in my class. What am I doing wrong here?

And, my script is like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAddToCart').click(function () {
            var data = $('#PurchaseForm').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'Post',
                url: '/Purchase/AddToCart',
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location = '/Purchase/AddToCart'
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Your code as it is posted should work (apart from being overly verbose). Without a [mcve] this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Which MVC (version)? What did you do to configure Sessions?

Comment: Sessions are disadvised anyway, try to think of another solution.

Comment: i am using MVC 5 and tried to use ViewBag but same output.

Comment: What are your session configs in the web.config? did you try to save a simple int or string in session and retrieve it?

Comment: ViewBag is very different, that was not supposed to work.

Comment: in this controller IsNewSession is true. but for other controller it is false. maybe this is the reason. how can i disable IsNewSession property?

Comment: here my data are coming from an ajax call.

Comment: You need to post your javascript that is making the request.

Comment: Did you remove the empty Session_Start method from your global.asax.cs?

Comment: yeah, there is no Session_Start method in global.asax.cs

Comment: take a look on my script:
`<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnAddToCart').click(function () {
                var data = $('#PurchaseForm').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'Post',
                    url: '/Purchase/AddToCart',
                    data: data,
                    success: function (response) {
                        window.location = '/Purchase/AddToCart'
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>`

Comment: Add it back then. https://forums.asp.net/t/1520827.aspx?IsNewSession+always+True+unless+there+is+Session_Start+in+global+asax+cs

Comment: In Asp.Net, Session works by mapping a cookie in the request containing the `session id` of a specific client to an object in server memory. In other words, it knows it was you because you have the cookie. Since you're making Ajax call it is possible that server is not getting session id. You can use inspection tool to make sure cookies are attached to the post and they contain session id.

Comment: just needed to return json() instead of empty view(). can anyone please explain the functionality?

Comment: how can i use callback function into my script here?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("currentUser", appUser);
```

And,

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"]
```

Answer (score 0):

just needed to return `json()` instead of empty `view()`.